# What happened to Knights of Ren?

Tags: star-wars, knights-of-ren

Kylo Ren corrupted some of Luke's students to create the Knights of Ren. But, why aren't we seeing these force guys?

Were the Snoke's red uniformed bodyguards the Knights of Ren? If so, why did they attack Kylo Ren after the death of Snoke?

Comment: Perhaps they were wiped out in a disgusting but hilarious battle with the Knights of Stimpy.

Answer (score 5):

At this point, we have enough info to partially answer your question. Snoke's Praetorian Guard **definitely weren't the remnants of Ren's personal hit-squad**. Not only were there more of them (eight Praetorians versus seven Knights of Ren) but the Knights are described in the [Ultimate Star Wars, New Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars,_New_Edition) factbook as being a) "loyal to Kylo Ren" rather than to Snoke and b) "Species: Unknown" whereas the Guards are described as "human".

> **The Knight of Ren**
>   **SPECIES**: Unknown
>   **HOMEWORLD**: Unknown
>   **AFFILIATION**: **Loyal to Kylo Ren**
>
> The Knights of Ren are **Kylo Ren's most deadly and mysterious servants.** With their bodies encased in rusty, battered armor and their faces permanently concealed beneath ominous masks—echoing that of the new Supreme Leader himself—even their species remains a mystery. What is obvious to anyone who witnesses them in action is that their fighting skills and martial prowess are without equal. Each Knight is armed with a lethally effective and unique weapon, suited to either long range or close-quarter combat.

---

Additionally, the director of *The Last Jedi* indicated that although he briefly considered making the Knights into Snoke's guard, this would have added an unneeded distraction from the fight scene and that having Kylo kill his former footsoldiers would require additional plotline in an already crowded film.

> *“We have a very full movie already there literally was just not room
>   for another element...I guess I could’ve used them in place of the
>   Praetorian guards but then it would feel like wasting them because all
>   those guards had to die,” Johnson told the Empire podcast. “And if
>   Kylo had some kind of connection to them it would’ve added a
>   complication that wouldn’t have helped the scene...truth is I just
>   didn’t see a place for them in the movie.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Rian Johnson Explains Why He Didn't Explore the Knights of Ren in 'The Last Jedi'](https://comicbook.com/2018/01/17/star-wars-the-last-jedi-knight-of-ren-rian-johnson-comments/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 4):

1. We never find out who exactly they were. There's nothing to confirm they were former Jedi students.
2. The Knights of Ren are not Snoke's Praetorian guards either. Kylo and Rey made short work of them in TLJ, while

   > the Knights of Ren appear in *Rise of Skywalker*. They are also not Palpatine's Praetorian guards either, as we see them all together at the end of ROS

It appears, based on the events of *Rise of Skywalker*, that

> they were, in some form, working for Palpatine and his Sith cult on Exogal. We can assume this based on the fact that they reappear only after Kylo makes it there. They also reappear in the Sith "pit" on Exogal to confront Kylo/Ben when Ben is trying to rescue Rey. Whomever they were, they were almost certainly part of the Sith cult, because it's hard to imagine them being allowed that far into the "pit" with their weapons without some trustworthiness.

Comment: From the comics, we know they're not the Jedi that Ben took. Ben and Luke fought them together prior to Ben leaving.